# ReactJS need to get some values from promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Firebase I have two Documents. one is "users" and "posts".

Inside posts, I have added an id equal to the "users" collection id.

What I'm trying to achieve is when I'm getting posts I need to get post-added user data.

I'm getting all the posts but I cannot get related user data. Can anyone help me do this?

```
import {
  collection,
  query,
  onSnapshot,
  orderBy,
  doc,
  getDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";

import { db } from "../../FireBaseConfig";

export default function Home() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState();

  const getPostUser = async (userID) => {
    try {
      const userQuery = doc(db, "users", userID);

      const userRef = await getDoc(userQuery);

      const userData = userRef.data();

      return userData;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPosts = async () => {
      try {
        const q = query(collection(db, "posts"), orderBy("statusDate", "desc"));

        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
          let posts_arr = [];
          let adsfadsfad = "";
          querySnapshot.forEach(async (item, index, array) => {
            getPostUser(item.data().id)
              .then((res) => {
                adsfadsfad.push(res);
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
              });

            console.log(adsfadsfad);

            posts_arr.push(
              <div className="home__posts--post" key={item.id}>
                <div className="home__posts--post-user flex items-center">
                  {/* <img
                      src={abc["avatar"]}
                      alt={abc["avatar"]}
                      className="w-[50px] h-[50px] rounded-full"
                    />
                    <h4>{abc["avatar"]}</h4> */}
                  {/* {asdasd} */}
                </div>
                <div>
                  {item.data().statusImage && (
                    <img
                      src={item.data().statusImage}
                      alt={item.data().status}
                    />
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          });
          setPosts(posts_arr);
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };

    getPosts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="home p-4 max-w-screen-sm mx-auto">
      <div className="home__posts">{posts}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is not really a `reactjs` topic. `Promise`s are a ECMAScript thing. _"...but I cannot get related user data."_ - Where's the connection to the title of the question?

Comment: `adsfadsfad` (what's with that name?) is a string (`let adsfadsfad = "";`) and not an array (`adsfadsfad.push(res);`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code also queries for user data for every post. In case all the posts returned by first query are posted by same person, it'll be redundant. Also the `getDoc()` (`getPostUser()`) returns a `Promise` so you need to handle that as well.  Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getPosts = async () => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "posts"), orderBy("statusDate", "desc"));

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, async (querySnapshot) => {
      const posts = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      }));

      // Get an array of unique user IDs from all posts
      const userIds = [...new Set(posts.map((post) => post.userId))];

      // Fetch documents of those users only
      const userPromises = userIds.map((userId) =>
        getDoc(doc(db, "users", userId))
      );

      const userDocs = await Promise.all(userPromises);

      // Record<string, UserDocumenData>
      const users = userDocs.reduce((acc, userDoc) => {
        acc[userDoc.id] = userDoc.data();
        return acc;
      }, {});

      // use "posts" array and "users" object to render your UI
      // You can get user info as shown below
      // const postUser = users[posts[0].userId]
    });
  };

  getPosts();
}, []);
```

If you want to, you can also additionally remove some `userId` from the second query in case their data has been fetched already.

Comment: Yes, this is working smoothly. Thank you Sooo mush @Dharmaraj